# No Output PDF Produced

Tags: errors, output, garamondx

I'm using TeXShop to produce a PDF file of a .tex file, and my professor can produce an output, but I cannot. I assume it has something to do with garamondx, but I believe I installed it correctly.

To install garamondx using getnonfreefonts, I used:

```
getnonfreefonts --sys -a
```

and it says all fonts are installed and no updates necessary.

Then when trying to Typeset the .tex file, I receive the error:

> !pdfTeX error: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex (file zgmr8r): Font zgmr8r at 600 n
> ot found
> ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! This message means pdflatex tries to make a bitmap font, instead of using the vector font.. Try to update the  list of postscript fonts using the command line `initexmf --mkmaps`.

Comment: Hi, should've included I'm on Mac. Terminal doesn't recognize that command